# Pass Class Type Parameter via ajax jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, list, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Class with following structure

```
public class MyType
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public string type{ get; set; }

    }


Public Class A
{
string Id{get;set;}
public List<MyType> aList{get;set;}
}
```

My ajax calling is following:

```
var listitem=[
{name:"a",type:1},
{name:"b",type:2},
{name:"c",type:3}
]

     $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ActionMethod", "Controller")',
                type: 'post',
                async: false,
                data: {
                    Id: 1,                    
                    aList :listitem

                },
                success: function (resp) {

                },
                error: function (resp) {
                }
            });
```

My Action Method is following:

```
 [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult ActionMethod(A adata)
            {
                return some action;

            }
```

I am getting value of Id in ActionMethod but list item is blank? how can i pass the list?

Comment: there should be a `sync` in `datatype` on your `client` and `server`, please share your `MyType` class as well

Comment: @manish MyType added

Comment: I think the problem is: Your data(aList ) is a list but your action method takes a single object.

Comment: `async:false` is a terrible idea for user-friendliness (because it locks the whole browser during the request) and also completely unnecessary in 99% of cases. Plus, some browsers have deprecated it, so you can expect it to stop working completely in the future.

Comment: @himyata action take list because aList count is 3 in action method but all value of list is null

Comment: @MAT14 is `adata` a list in `public ActionResult ActionMethod(A adata)`?

Comment: your `API` expects the `type` property of `MyType` class to be `string` but from `client` side your passing it as `number`. Try changing it to `string` and that should do the trick.

   `var listitem=[
     { name: "a", type: "1"},
     { name: "b", type: "2"},
     { name: "c", type: "3"}
    ];`

Comment: @manish corrected but still not working i got aList count is 3 but name and id is null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var adata = {
    Id: 1,
    aList: [
        { name: "a", type: 1 },
        { name: "b", type: 2 },
        { name: "c", type: 3 }
    ]
}

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("ActionMethod", "Controller")',
    type: 'post',
    data: JSON.stringify(adata),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (resp) {

    },
    error: function (resp) {
    }
});
```

Comment: You also need to set `contentType: 'application/json'` (and never use `async: false`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks. I edited the code

Comment: I forgot to add content type thanks